# ant design progress bar. Using steps prevents full width

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progress-bar, antd

I cant seem to create a full-width progress bar with steps. It works normally with the normal progress bar.

```
<Progress percent={50} />
    <br />
  <Progress percent={50} steps={3} />
```

Example can be found here     https://codepen.io/NidorPL/pen/QWdyRKN?editors=001

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Overrwrite css properties

```
    & .ant-progress-steps-item{
          width: 95px !important;
     }
```